# mysql to Propel

Tags: mysql, symfony1

I need the following sql query converting to Propel:

```
SELECT tag.tag, count( content_tag.tag_id ) AS weight
FROM content_tag, tag
WHERE content_tag.tag_id = tag.id
GROUP BY content_tag.tag_id
ORDER BY weight DESC , tag.ord_id ASC
```

Any ideas on how to do the count clause?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addJoin(ContentTagPeer::TAG_ID,TagPeer::ID,Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$c->add(ContentTagPeer::TAG_ID, 'Count(' . ContentTagPeer::TAG_ID . ') AS Weight' , Criteria::CUSTOM);
$c->addGroupByColumn(ContentTagPeer::TAG_ID);
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(TagPeer::ORD_ID);
$c->addDescendingOrderByColumn('Weight');
```

I think that could help solve it

Comment: I think you missed the Alias for the COUNT column. That Criteria won't work. In your third line, the second parameter should go like `'COUNT('.ContentTagPeer::TAG_ID.') AS WEIGHT'`.